# How to get File object from response body in OkHttp?

Tags: android, okhttp

I download videos using OkHttp in my application. To play the video, I need to download it completely and then play it using a File object.

I couldn't find a good way to get the File object from the underlying DiskLruCache in OkHttp. Right now I use the InputStream of response body to pipe the response in another DiskLruCache in order to receive a File object and play it.

I think it's not a good idea to have multiple DiskLruCaches. Is there any good way to get a File object from the cached response in OkHttp?

Comment: Why cache it, can you not save on the file system ?

Comment: @LaurentMeyer If I use OkHttp cache and save a temp file to play the video, I'm doing the same thing twice, as the response is already saved in OkHttp's DiskLruCache. I want to eliminate the double saving of the video file on disk. I use the second DiskLruCache to manage multiple temp files and also to disable OkHttp's cache for video responses. This way I save videos on disk only once. But I'm using two caches, one for videos, and one for the rest of responses, while it's theoretically possible to use a single cache for all responses, if only OkHttp could provide response as a File object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t, and you shouldn’t want to anyway. The problem is that OkHttp’s disk cache may evict files as you’re using them. It doesn’t have any mechanism to pin a file for a purpose other than its own.

Instead you need to manage the lifecycle of these downloads manually: how many to store, when to delete them, etc.